# How can I view my html page on browser like in printing preview

Tags: javascript, java, html, page-break

I have a html file with a table tag. This has a `theader`, `tbody` and `tfooter`.
The data in the table body are realy long. So I want that it splits when it's bigger then A4 size.
It works greate when I try to preview it for printing.
The data continue in a new page with header and footer from table.
Is there a way to show the same in my web browser?
My html file is something like that...

```
<table border="1">
   <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Anz Bezeichnung</th><th>Preis</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>orange</td>
      <td>20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>orange</td>
      <td>20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>all the datas like this</td>
      <td>20</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean with do the same in your browser

Comment: realy sorry for that.i know it sound a bit differend.i just want that if the datas in the table are too big for the page(for example A4 format) it should create a new page below and keep show the datas there.when i press File -> print review it shows exactly what i wana see but in my browser its like unending page.

Comment: I guess i know what you mean, but i am afraid you will need to use or pagination or scroll, to avoid the unending page

Comment: but how ?can u give me an example please

Comment: what approach do you prefer? add scroll to the table or pagination?

Comment: it would greate if i can create pages with pagination.i mean like in a pdf

Comment: the option with datatables would be something like this https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Comment: i mean more like if i could scroll down to other pages.sorry if i describe it wrong

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use datatable which has inbuilt fuction for print.[Check out DataTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html).

for A4 size you can modify paging option

Comment: is it better if i try to build it with java ?because actually i am trying to generate a invoice .